# Beginning Java: Sorting method explanation

Tags: java

This is an example of a sorting method written out:

```
    int sorting = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length-1; i++){
        for(int s = i+1; s<myArray.length; s++){
            if(myArray[i] > myArray[s]){
                sorting = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = myArray[s]; 
                myArray[s] = sorting; 
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't understand parts of it like the part of:

> ```
>     for(int s = i+1; s<myArray.length; s++){
>         if(myArray[i] > myArray[s]){
>             sorting = myArray[i];
>             myArray[i] = myArray[s]; 
>             myArray[s] = sorting; 
>         }
>     }
> ```

Can someone take their time and explain to me the whole process, why myArray[s] is initialized to sorting and all of that in steps or simple explanation?

It's really getting me confused because it's so abstract. Can anyone help? It's supposed to sort numbers from least to greatest.

PS: I understand that the for loops are comparing the 1st number with the 2nd and subsequent numbers. But after that, it seems a bit hard to grasp.

Comment: Looks like bubble sort from here.  *Very* inefficient sort.  Any further elaboration would be copying either an algorithms book or Wikipedia, really.

Comment: Yeah well, I'm a beginner right now so I'm not really concerned with the efficiency of things. Only the way it works so I know why it does what it does. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Makoto is correct this is something that you can easily find with a simple google search [This is one of many](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this explanation helps

> Loop invariant: The elements upto i - 1 are sorted, from i are all
>   greater or equal

```
// "The elements upto -1 (=none) are sorted, from 0 are all greater or equal"
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++){

    // The elements upto  i-1 are sorted, from i are all greater or equal
    for (int s = i+1; s < myArray.length; s++) { // For the elements after i
        if (myArray[i] > myArray[s]) { // If there is a smaller one
            // Swap the elements at i and s:
            int oldValueAtI = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = myArray[s]; 
            myArray[s] = oldValueAtI; 
        }
    }
    // myArray[i] is smallest for s > i
    // The elements upto  i are sorted, from i+1 are all greater or equal
}
// The elements upto s.length - 1 are sorted,
// from s.length (=none) are all greater or equal

// All elements are sorted
```

---

So you could even simplify things, doing less swaps:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++){
    // Search the smallest in the rest:
    int smallestS = i;
    for (int s = i+1; s < myArray.length; s++) {
        if (myArray[s] < myArray[smallestS]) {
            smallestS = s;
        }
    }
    // Swap the elements at i and smallestS
    if (smallestS != i) { // Check not needed
        int oldValueAtI = myArray[i];
        myArray[i] = myArray[smallestS]; 
        myArray[smallestS] = oldValueAtI;
    } 
}
```